# Django query one to many based on extra condition

Tags: django, django-orm

I have code set up like this:

```
class User(models.Model):
   email = models.EmailField(_(u'email address'), max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True, blank=True)

class Verification(models.Model):
   created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='verifications')
   category = models.CharField(choices=constants.VERIFICATION_CATEGORY_CHOICES, default=None, max_length=255)
   status = models.CharField(_(u'verification status'), max_length=255, default=constants.STATUS_PENDING, blank=True, null=True)
```

Now I need to get a list of users who has "ID"(category) verification and verification status is "APPROVED". How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this(using related_name `verifications` as reverse relation):

```
 User.objects.filter(verifications__category="ID", verifications_status="APPROVED")
```

Comment: thank you so much. it works!   User.objects.filter(verifications__category="ID", verifications__status="APPROVED")